# Requesting access token for second API which needs consent step

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-identity-platform

Currently developing a **React** SPA with different API calls. I have ended up having a *User Experience API* which handles different calls for other APIs in the background with their access tokens what *UX API* is requesting from `oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint. The application is using *OBO* - on behalf of - flow explained in the following article: 
 [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

For my web application which is hosted in **Azure** has the following *simplified* architecture:

[image: architecture]

**Code and issues:**

So in the *UX API* - which is an **Azure Function v2.0** - I'm trying to get the proper *access token* for other *Data 2 API* - see in the architecture above - based on the steps explained in the mentioned Microsoft documentation.

Explaining the scenario:

1. First the user opens the application then it needs to consent the authorization for *UX API*,
2. Then in successful login access token arrives which can be used to call *UX API*,
3. In the *UX API* requesting access token for *Data 2 API* - see code implementation below,
4. The response arrives where user needs to consent about authorization for the *Data 2 API*.

See below the code implementation which seems to be working fine:

```
const {authorization} = context.bindings.req.headers;
const config = {
   method: 'post',
   url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<our-tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
   data: qs.stringify({
      'scope': 'https://<data-2-api-resource-url>/access_as_user',
      'client_id': '<application client id>',
      'client_secret': '<app-client-secret>',
      'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'requested_token_use': 'on_behalf_of',
      'assertion': authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
   }),
   httpsAgent: agent
};

const res = await axios(config);
const accessToken = res.data.access_token;
```

Which throws the following exception *in the background*:

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID `'<app-client-id>'` named `'<app-name>'`. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

**Questions:**

Of course I was walking through similar issues explained here in *StackOverflow* but I guess this issue is different from them. They are talking about only one layer scenario and those are explaining what the error message means which looks clear.

So my question is how should I deal with the scenario? My guesses below which might be wrong:

1. Should not be handled somehow in configuration for apps that if a valid access token is coming from *UX API* then no consent is needed further?
2. Send back to user the interaction window to consent about the authorization for the *Data 2 API* which does not make a great UX for the end user.
3. Change somehow the whole authorization flow from on-behalf-of?

Not sure, I appreciate any help!

Comment: There is the authorized applications section in the app registration's Expose an API blade. There you can specify which apps can use which scopes. Another choice which might work is the knownClientApplications array in the manifest of the API app. You can add the client id of the front-end app there to do simultaneous consent.

Comment: @juunas Thanks for the answer, the authorized application section did the job, works like charm! Would you like to make as answer, so I can accept as the one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the authorized applications section in the app registration's Expose an API blade. There you can specify which apps can use which scopes. Another choice which might work is the knownClientApplications array in the manifest of the API app. You can add the client id of the front-end app there to do simultaneous consent.

Comment: So from my architecture, I added the *UX API*'s application (client) id to *Data 2 API*'s **Authorized client applications** section which made it work. That was only missing piece. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pleased to see that this worked - great stuff by both of you! Allowing the user to login once then access multiple related resources is a common requirement.

The above solution feels a lot better than making the UI do silent redirects for each resource - which is especially difficult for an SPA due to use of iframes.